# Is there any difference between QRegularExpression and QRegExp?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qregexp

I see there is a new class for regular expressions - `QRegularExpression`. Is it just a typedef for QRegExp, or a new class, or what? And why do we need it, we already have QRegExp?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Ok, after some more digging into the docs, I found it really is a new class, it has improvements, but it is only available in Qt5, so you can't use it if you want to compile on both Qt4 and Qt5:

> Notes for QRegExp Users
>
> The QRegularExpression class introduced in Qt 5 is a big improvement upon QRegExp, in terms of APIs offered, supported pattern syntax and speed of execution. The biggest difference is that QRegularExpression simply holds a regular expression, **and it's not modified** when a match is requested. Instead, a QRegularExpressionMatch object is returned, in order to check the result of a match and extract the captured substring. The same applies with global matching and QRegularExpressionMatchIterator.

Comment: Yeah, well, I spent some time trying to write comprehensive documentation for QRegularExpession, so there's that :)

Comment: I wrote the entire class. If you think docs could be improved, please submit such a suggestion on the bugreport.

Comment: "- You wrote that part of the doc?" "- I wrote the entire class." This made me lol.

Comment: Thanks @peppe both for writing the entire class and the doc! That beaing said,  I really think that the first line of the the following two URLs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html & http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html should say "please note, there are TWO regex systems in Qt [...]"

Comment: Well, there's a note in QRegExp documentation saying that QRegularExpression is the recommended class to use in Qt 5; OTOH QRegularExpression docs treat extensively the problem of porting away from QRegExp. Feel free to submit suggestions on how to improve the wording on Qt's bugtracker.

Comment: @peppe, Does it support look behinds? I can't seem to find any references for this in the docs.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: yes, it does support fixed-length look behinds. It supports anything on the [pcresyntax(3) manual page](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html), with the exception of callouts, duplicated named capture groups and other such small limitations (as listed in the class docs).

Answer (score 9):

At least for Qt 4.8. I can give a very practical reason to use `QRegularExpressions` instead of `QRegExp`:

Do these look dangerous to you?

```
int index = myQString.indexOf(myQRegExp);
bool okay = myQString.contains(myQRegExp);
```

Both lines can corrupt your heap, crash or hang your application. I experienced heap corruption and hang with Qt 4.8. The blog post [QString::indexOf() versus Qt 4.5](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2008/11/04/910/) explains that `QString::indexOf()` modifies a `const QRegExp` object. `QString::contains()` inlines `QString::indexOf()` so it's the same problem.

If you're stuck with Qt4 and thus QRegExp, you could use

```
int index = myQRegExp.indexIn(myQString);
bool okay = (myQRegExp.indexIn(myQString) != -1);
```

in your sources instead. Or patch the Qt Sources.